# the meaning of "to pitch"

Tags: word-meaning

> In 1968, he submitted a letter to the secretary of the South African
>   parliament, asking to **pitch** conservative legislators on a
>   treatment program that would rehabilitate gays and lesbians.

(Dr. Shock, The Walrus, SEPTEMBER 2015 )

What does "**to pitch**" mean here?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It basically means "persuade", i.e. to encourage someone to do something.

> **pitch**
>   *verb*
>
> *(mainly US)* to try to persuade someone to do something

*Source: Cambridge Dictionaries Online (British)*